# How to update a field on a document, that is based on another document on Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For example:
I have a document `sales` and a document `customer` on a Firestore.

I need to link a `customer` (or `customers`) on a `sale`, and, if the **customer's name changes** (or another data, linked in the `sale`), I need it reflects on `sales` document. How can I do that?

- I need to create a `customer_id` (references) on `sales`?
- Or I need to use Google Functions triggers (like `afterUpdate`) on `customers` document, to update all the documents that have `customer's` shared data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your normalize all the data by pointing every reference to some data to the one document where it's also up to date, or you write some code to keep all the references up to date.  The client can update all the references itself, or you could use Cloud Functions to do it automatically.  It's up to you to pick one that meets your needs.

Comment: Could you explain "The client can update all the references itself"
Can I do it without Functions?

Comment: Sure, write code on the client that locates and changes all the documents. It may or may not be possible for your case, but it's common.

Comment: Hmmm, do it on client-side, sure! Thanks :)